# Manual unstake a Solana NFT

Tags: nft, staking

So, with the project I'm working with **we have 2 staking sites, an old one (https://stake.wobblebug.info/) and a new one (https://wobblebug.io/stake).** The developer for the old one there was a number of issues with and now is mostly unreachable due to personal problems. For the most part, it's been okay moving people to the new staking site but occasionally we're having **some people log into the old staking site**, and even though we can confirm through SolScan that their NFTs are still in the staking wallet and they were the last transaction - they **can't see thier NFTs on the old site and therefore can't unstake them.**

With all of them, I **go through restarting/resigning in, clearing cache, revoking authorization and as a last step I suggest doing a wallet refresh.** Unfortunately for a few of these people, none of these solutions seem to work. Although one of the ones that couldn't see it and none of these worked for did randomly have them become visible again so it seems like something fixable.

**This is one we're currently having an issue with: https://solscan.io/token/EZrstCp3UmorybPpFJqjbRT2VLs4Fsefc5bLjAoq44AE**

I was **looking at other possible solutions and came across how to manually unstake an NFT but it was for an ETH NFT (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3gJ-v4UDhQM&t=98s)**. I was wondering if there is **something similar for a SOL NFT to manually unstake them?** Or if anyone has **any other suggestions.**

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think you need to call the instruction for the program yourself. Not through the website

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from the details you provided is that your users had previously delegated/staked NFTs to some other account and you now want to revoke their access.
[This is answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73093078/13918939)

> spl-token revoke <MINT_ADDRESS>

For using this command you would need to install solana cli.

If this doesn't answer your question you can also refer to [this page](https://docs.solana.com/cli/delegate-stake).